# Consolidate and append Date and Hour columns based on Timestamp column

Tags: text-processing

I have a csv file with sample data entries as follows:

```
Timestamp,data1,data2
2018 07 16 13:00:00,23,45
2018 07 16 13:10:00,23,45
2018 07 16 13:20:00,23,45
2018 07 16 13:30:00,23,45
2018 07 16 13:50:00,23,45
2018 07 16 14:20:00,23,45
2018 07 16 14:40:00,23,45
2018 07 16 14:50:00,23,45
2018 07 16 15:10:00,23,45
2018 07 16 17:50:00,23,45
2018 07 16 18:10:00,23,45
2018 07 17 10:10:00,23,45
2018 07 18 13:20:00,23,45
2018 07 19 13:30:00,23,45
```

What I would like to do is create other 2 columns, `Date` & `Hour`. The `Date` column will contain the date, and the `Hour` column will contain all the hours at which data was captured. For example, based on the data above, I would like to have the following output (same file, just adding extra 2 columns):

```
Date,Hour
2018 07 16,13
2018 07 16,14
2018 07 16,15
2018 07 16,17
2018 07 16,18
2018 07 17,10
2018 07 18,13
2018 07 19,13
```

**For example, if there are entries on hour 13 (whether 1 or many) on 2018 07 16, list the corresponding date and hour 13 only once and move on to entries with different hour until date changes. and process repeats.**

Please note that the file has many entries (100000+) for many days, with varying number of data captured in an hour as above. How can i go about solving this problem? I hope my explanation is clear enough.

Comment: Why do you want to **append** the date and hour? The records already have those at the beginning of each line.  That would leave you with records like `2018 07 16 13:00:00,23,45,2018 07 16,13`.  Wouldn't it make more sense to just have `Date,Hour,data1,data2`? e.g. `2018 07 16,13,23,45`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS=FS="," }
  NR==1{ print "Date", "Hour"; next }
  {
    $0=substr($1, 1, 10) FS substr($1, 12, 2)
    if ($0 == prev) next  # skip to next record if record equals prev
    prev=$0               # remember record
  }
  1                       # print record
' file
```

Thus, the date string consists of the first 10 characters starting at position 1 of the first field and the hour is extracted from 2 characters starting at position 12.

Both values plus a field separator (`FS`) are assigned to the record (`$0`) and printed if the previous remembered record is different.

Comment: Thank you for your response. please note that the hour has to appear once as in the desired output above. if there are entries on hour 13 (whether 1 or many), list the corresponding date and hour 13 only once. new columns wont be the same size as the Timestamp column.

Comment: Please see the update.

Comment: thank you, this solves my problem.

Comment: i would also like to calculate hourly average for data1 &data2. must i post a new question or I can amend this one?

Comment: @dante_t Yes, please post a new question with input and expected output. You can add a link to this question if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

`sort` and `uniq` can give you the output example shown in your question.

```
$ sed -e 's/Timestamp.*/Date,Hour/; s/ \(..\):.*/,\1/' file.csv  | uniq
Date,Hour
2018 07 16,13
2018 07 16,14
2018 07 16,15
2018 07 16,17
2018 07 16,18
2018 07 17,10
2018 07 18,13
2018 07 19,13
```

However, you also said that you wanted these two new fields appended to the current input lines.   That doesn't make a lot of sense to me, because then you'd end up with the Date and the Hour duplicated in each line (they're already at the beginning of each line in the Timestamp field).

The following isn't exactly what you asked for but is, IMO, an improvement.

Instead of appending Date & Hour to the end of each line, it just uses `sed` to transform the existing Timestamp field into Date and Hour fields.  Then `uniq` is used to get rid of duplicate lines.

```
$ sed -e 's/Timestamp/Date,Hour/; s/ \(..\):[^,]*,/,\1,/' file.csv  | uniq
Date,Hour,data1,data2
2018 07 16,13,23,45
2018 07 16,14,23,45
2018 07 16,15,23,45
2018 07 16,17,23,45
2018 07 16,18,23,45
2018 07 17,10,23,45
2018 07 18,13,23,45
2018 07 19,13,23,45
```

This assumes that the input file is already in Timestamp order.

NOTE: if values for `data1` or `data2` can vary, the output lines will not be unique and the line will be printed.  This is because `uniq` compares the entire line against the previous line  (`uniq` can be made to skip fields, but only recognises whitespace as a field separator and can't be made to use commas, nor can it be made to use only the first two fields).  If that's what you want, then it'll work as is.

Otherwise, you'd need to use `awk` or `perl` or something instead of `uniq` to check for uniqueness.  e.g. the following uses `awk` to compare only the first two comma-separated fields (i.e. Date and Hour):

```
$ sed -e 's/Timestamp/Date,Hour/; s/ \(..\):[^,]*,/,\1,/' file.csv  |
    awk -F, 'prev != $1$2 {print; prev=$1$2}'
```

But if you're going to pipe the output of `sed` into `awk`, you may as well just use `awk` alone, as awk can do everything that `sed` can do - that's what awk's `sub()`, `gsub()`, and `gensub()` functions are for.  e.g.

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ sub(/Timestamp/,"Date,Hour");
                       $1 = gensub(/ ([0-9]+):.*/,",\\1",1,$1)
                    };
                    prev != $1$2 {print; prev=$1$2}' file.csv
```

or with `perl`:

```
$ perl -lne 's/Timestamp/Date,Hour/;
             s/ (\d\d):.*?,/,$1,/;
             ($current) = (m/^[^,]+,\d\d|^Date),/);
             if ($prev ne $current) {print ; $prev = $current}' file.csv
```

Comment: Thank you for your input sir, very much appreciated. i figured it's actually ok to create a new file instead of appending the input file.